# Unable to convert date/time format from character to numeric column (for sentiment analysis) in R

Tags: r

After reading a CSV into R I'm struggling to convert the date 'Created' column from a character to numeric column so that I can run sentiment analysis on the Message column and visualise in ggplot. Think it is because of the date/time format (especially the mix of GMT/BST stamp) but N/As are then introduced when attempting convert the column to as.numeric. My intention is to just use Y/M/D data for the ggplot.

```
x <- data.frame(Page.Name= c("a","b","c"), Created = c("2020-07-16 17:52:14 BST","2020-04-16 14:52:14 GMT","2020-07-16 19:00:25 GMT"), 
             Message = c("Opener Dom Sibley and all-rounder Ben Stokes were at the crease for England at Tea","Dominic Sibley & Ben Stokes Look to Continue Partnership","Ben Stokes gets his 50 too! England cross 200"))

x$Created<-factor(x$Created)

#Warning message:NAs introduced by coercion


x %>% mutate(dialogue_split = get_sentences(Message),
     day = floor_date(Created, "day"))%% 
     sentiment_by(dialogue_split, list(Page.Name, Created)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(day, ave_sentiment, fill = ave_sentiment)) + 
     geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
     labs(x = "day",
     y = "average sentiment",
     title = "sentiment of tweets",
     subtitle = "Polarity analzyed using {sentimentr}",
     fill = "polarity")

#Error in UseMethod("reclass_date", orig) : no applicable method for 'reclass_date' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `lubridate` you can do:

```
library(lubridate)

x %>% 
  mutate(Created = ymd_hms(Created, tz = 'GMT'))
```

Which gives you:

```
> class(x$Created)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Or if you just want date, as you mentioned, you can do:

```
x %>% 
  mutate(Created = ymd_hms(Created, tz = 'GMT'),
         Created = as_date(Created))
```

Which gives you:

```
> x$Created
[1] "2020-07-16" "2020-04-16" "2020-07-16"
```

Edit:

Here's more of a full solution since you are running into other issues.

Note that `sentiment_by` creates a `data.frame` object, so it can't be used within a `mutate` call.

```
library(lubridate)
library(sentimentr)

x <- data.frame(Page.Name= c("a","b","c"), Created = c("2020-07-16 17:52:14 BST","2020-04-16 14:52:14 GMT","2020-07-16 19:00:25 GMT"), 
                Message = c("Opener Dom Sibley and all-rounder Ben Stokes were at the crease for England at Tea","Dominic Sibley & Ben Stokes Look to Continue Partnership","Ben Stokes gets his 50 too! England cross 200"))

# Clean up your date
x <- x %>% mutate(dialogue_split = get_sentences(Message),
            Created = ymd_hms(Created, tz = 'GMT'),
            Created = as_date(Created)) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  group_by(Page.Name, Created) 

# Get polarity/sentiment data
sent <- sentiment_by(y$dialogue_split, by = list(y$Page.Name, y$Created))

# Join polarity/sentiment data back to `x`  
x <- left_join(x, sent, by = c("Page.Name", "Created"))

# Plot 
x %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Created, ave_sentiment, fill = ave_sentiment)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "day",
       y = "average sentiment",
       title = "sentiment of tweets",
       subtitle = "Polarity analzyed using {sentimentr}",
       fill = "polarity")
```

[image]

Comment: That's great - thank you. I'm now getting an error message on using sentimentr

`Error in sentiment_by(dialogue_split, list(Page.Name, Created)) : 
  object 'dialogue_split' not found`

any ideas?

Comment: I updated the post. I believe the reason you're getting that error is because `sentiment_by` produces a `data.frame` object. If this post answers your question, please consider marking is as accepted by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: much much appreciated